# Find $f(x)$ such that $f(x) = 1 + \frac1{x} \int_1^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, integral-equations

I need to find a continuous function defined for real and positive $x$ such that $f(x)  = 1 + \frac1{x} \int_1^x f(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$. What I did is the following:

$$\begin{align*}f(x) &= 1 + \frac1{x} \int_1^x f(t)\ \mathrm{d}t\\
x(f(x) - 1) &= \int_1^x f(t) \  \mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}$$

Differentiating both sides:

$$\begin{align*}
f(x) - 1 + x f'(x) &= f(x)\\
f'(x) &= \frac1{x}\\
f(x) &= \ln x
\end{align*}$$

Which looks alright. But when checking to make sure, I get this:

$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= 1 + \frac1{x} \int_1^x \ln t \ \mathrm{d}t\\
f(x) &= 1 + \frac1{x} (x(\ln x -1)|_1^x)\\
f(x) &= 1 + \frac1{x} (x(\ln x -1) - (\ln 1 - 1))\\
f(x) &= 1 + \ln x - 1 + \frac1{x}\\
f(x) &= \ln x + \frac1{x}
\end{align*}$$

which is different from what I got before. What is my mistake here?

Comment: How about the constant when integrating 1/x into lnx?

Comment: You are correct up to here: $ f'(x) = 1/x.$ However, that does not imply immediately $ f(x) = \ln x$, but rather $ f(x) = \ln x + C $ where $C$ is the arbitrary constant of integration.

Comment: We have $f(x)=\ln x +C$. Evaluate $C$ by going back to the original equation and putting $x=1$.  The integral dies, and you get $\ln( 1) + C=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You left out the constant of integration... the answer is actually $\ln(x) + 1$.

Comment: That was dumb. Thanks.